# NAS Mounted as AFP mounts an SMB connection by itself

Tags: macos, nas

I've been running into trouble recently with a NAS device, Seagate 5TB storage system with a Linux back-end. Whenever I connect to the device with an AFP connection, the drive connects with no issues, and I can browse files and folders with ease. After a while though, Yosemite decides to mount another version of the NAS using SMB. This SMB connection is riddled with issues; folder names show off an old 8.3 NTFS name, and sometimes they cannot be changed.

How can I stop my Mac from connecting an additional SMB connection the NAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clear your login credentials out of your keychain.**

For instance, on my Synology Diskstation NAS, I have the following saved for SMB:

[image]

Once you delete it, OS X will no longer try to connect to the share.

Comment: This was the case, but it also turns out that I had favorites mapped to an older SMB connection. I've since re-added all the favorites to be under the AFP connection. Thanks for the answer, even if it was a bit simple! :)

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple ones that get us tripped up.  I've been there many times!  :-)